# Aptana's FTP connection and synchronisation

Tags: php, javascript, html, aptana

I am currently using Aptana to edit files and upload them directly to the webserver whenever I save them. But it's a big project I am working on and I regularly need to search for a specific line, or piece of code, in multiple files. it's literally 100's of files, and Aptana's search function does not work directly on FTP.

Now my question is, is there a way to store all the files locally AND sync them through FTP whenever I save them?

Answer (score 0):

If it is a big project you should really consider not editing your files live on your server, but edit them locally and use some kind of revisioning system (cvs, mercury, svn, git, clearcase, perforce, ...). Have you considered your options on using an external tool to sync your files from your local copy? Such as rsync or scp.

Do you work in a Windows or Unix environment?